# Fix misra 14.4 violation in macro function

Tags: c, misra, coverity

I get misra 14.4 violation saying " the condition exprecssion "0" does not have an essential boolean type"

It is a function defined as a macro

How can I fix this violation ?

```
#define function(a,b,c) do { \

< some -code > \
} while (0)
```

How can I solve this ?

I tried using while (false) and while (1 == 0) instead of while (0)
But the violations was not fixed

Comment: "I tried using while (false)" -- that seems like the right way to address this violation to me, because `false` should be essentially boolean, and rule 14.3 has an explicit exception for `do {... } while(false)` structures. What was the output of the misra-checker when you tried that?

Comment: It might be a matter of configuring the static analyzer correctly - it has to know which boolean type that is used, since MISRA C also allows C90 code.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi,  while(false) while (0 ==1), all these work if it is a normal function, but does not work in macro function

Comment: ``while (false)`` is not a MISRA C violation, assuming the tool is correctly configured.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation to use `do ... while(0)` macros was removed between MISRA C:2004 and 2012 (this might be one of the few places where I actually managed to influence the committee), because MISRA C already has a rule that only compound statements `{}` are allowed. Meaning that `do-while(0)` is a counter-productive trick that may hide MISRA violations. In a MISRA context, it is a good thing if code such as `if(cond) macro();` yields a compiler error, because it isn't MISRA compliant. And the MISRA compliant `if(cond) { macro(); }`  will not need `do-while(0)`.

Details here:
[What is do { } while(0) in macros and should we use it?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/279576)

If you still insist to use such macros then `do { ... } while(false)` ought to silence the static analyzer.

Also note that `0` in an expression which is intended to be unsigned is yet another MISRA C violation that might annoy the analyzer - `0u` would be correct.

Comment: You weren't the only one... The problem with ``do { ... } while(false)`` was that it restricted legitimate uses of macros, while not addressing other pitfalls - the 2012/2023 approach is better but probably can still be improved.